# Concatenate const char* C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char, constants, ofstream

```
basic_string<TCHAR> titleChar( szTitle );
string titleStr( titleChar.begin(), titleChar.end() );
const char* Songtitle = titleStr.c_str();

basic_string<TCHAR> artisTChar( szArtist );
string artitstStr( artisTChar.begin(), artisTChar.end() );
const char* Artistitle= artitstStr.c_str();
```

I'm trying to concatenate two const char* variables Songtitle & Artistitle. After concatenating i want simply write in a text file using ofstream

```
ofstream file;
file.open("D:\\lrc\\lyricsub\\songname.txt");
file << Songtitle;
file.close();
```

Comment: concatenate them as string them call c_str()

Comment: With `file << Songtitle << Artistitle; `, no need to concatenate in to string...

Comment: Your conversion from `TCHAR`-based strings to narrow strings will produce essentially random characters if there's something that can't fit in a `char` and you're building with `UNICODE` defined (which you should be in a modern Windows application). Most characters out there can't fit into a `char`.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks you this worked easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for all that code, nor for the concatenation:

```
std::string_view title { szTitle, strlen(szTitle) };
std::string_view artist_name { szArtist, strlen(szArtist) };
ofstream file;
file.open("D:\\lrc\\lyricsub\\songname.txt");
file << title << ' ' << artist_name;
file.close();
```

Note that this code, which uses [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)'s, will *not allocate any extra space*, which is a Good Thing. Although it might not really matter for a couple of short strings.

Comment: Thanks @einpolum 
What about using strcpy ?
`char concatSname[200];
 strcpy(concatSname,Artsttitle);
 strcat(concatSname," ");
 strcat(concatSname,Songtitle);`
This solved but when i tried achieving your method, string_view is not working

Comment: @Nik: 1. Bottom line: Absolutely not, you simply don't need to copy anything. 2. 200 is an arbitrary size. 3. You can't assume your stack is large enough to fit a string without being able to bound its size apriori. 3. You meant `strncpy()`. 4. This code will walk the strings multiple times - that's a waste. 5. Why write C code in C++?  6. When you really need to concatenate strings in a buffer, you'd probably use an `std::stringstream`.

Comment: thanks i got it. I have simply concatenated with  `file << title << ' ' << artist_name;` and it worked

Comment: @enipoklum would be great if you vote up my question , thanks